# Portable app after Windows 7 crash runs minimized and doesn't appear in taskbar

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

I have a portable app installed in Windows 7 that appears to have a bug. If windows experiences a power failure crash when its window is minimized, thereafter it reopens minimized when I run it again after rebooting, but the program's icon doesn't appear in the taskbar, so I can't get its window back.

Task manager shows that the program is in fact running. If the program's window is open normally or maximized when windows crashes, there is no problem the next time I run the app. The problem only happens if it was minimized.

How can I open its window, or do I have uninstall the program and start over?

I should mention that its window doesn't show up when I alt-tab through the windows either.

Switch-to in task manager simply minimizes the task manager.

I hate to say which app because it's bootleg software. Could something be done in Process Explorer? It gives more information than task manager.

Or maybe refresh the windows explorer taskbar somehow with the app running?

Comment: What happens if you do “Switch To” from the “Applications” tab of Task Manager?  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: What portable app?

Comment: I solved it! I went into Process Explorer, right clicked on the app's icon, and selected Restart. That killed and restarted the app, but this time with its window open as usual and its icon displayed in the taskbar! Maybe this will help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it! I went into Process Explorer, right clicked on the app's icon, and selected Restart. That killed and restarted the app, but this time with its window open as usual and its icon displayed in the taskbar! Maybe this will help someone else